# KarateDSL: Using proxy for UI automation, does not open url using that proxy

Tags: karate

I know the UI automation is in experimental state.

When I am trying to open an url using proxy, its not opening the right version of the URL. Is this isn't supported yet? Or is there anything I am missing?

```
Background:
   * configure proxy = 'http://URL:PORT'
   * configure driver = { type: 'chrome', headless: false }
...

  Given driver <url>
  And driver.input("input[id=XYZ]", 'NAME')
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for raising this, we have indeed missed this and opened an issue. Do try contribute ! https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/924

Comment: I tried to use selenium-server to create a workaround for my job. When I am trying to call my java method from feature file I am getting the following error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V. Can you help me in resolving this, so that I can use my temporary solution to complete my task?

Comment: @ShafiqulKabir we don't support selenium server, sorry